# What is the difference between 'sort -u' and 'uniq'?

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I need script that sorts a text file and remove the duplicates.
Most, if not all, of the examples out there use the `sort file1 | uniq > file2` approach.
In the [man sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) though, there is an -u option that does this at the time of sorting.

Is there a reason to use one over the other? Maybe availability to the -u option? Or memory/speed concern?

Comment: utter duplicate of [What is the difference between “sort -u” and “sort | uniq”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76049/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-sort-uniq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's about availability. Most systems I've ever seen have `sort` and `uniq` as they are usually provided by the same package. I just checked a Solaris system from 2001 and it's `sort` has the `-u` option.

Technically, using a linux pipe (`|`)  launches a subshell and is going to be more resource intensive as it requests multiple pid's from the OS.

If you go to the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c) for `sort`, which comes in the `coreutils` package, you can see that it actually just skips printing duplicates as it's printing its own sorted list and doesn't make use of the independent `uniq` [code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/uniq.c).

To see how it works follow the link to sort's source and see the functions below this comment:

> ```
>  /* If uniquified output is turned on, output only the first of
>    an identical series of lines. */
> ```

Although I believe `sort -u` should be faster, the performance gains are really going to be minimal unless you're running `sort | uniq` on huge files, as it will have to read through the entire file again.

Answer (score 5):

They should be equivalent in the simple case, but will behave differently if you're using the `-k` option to define only certain *fields* of the input line to use as sort keys.  In that case, `sort -u` will suppress lines which have the *same key* even if other parts of the line differ, whereas `uniq` will only suppress lines that are exactly identical.

```
$ cat example 
foo baz
quux ping
foo bar
$ sort -k 1,1 --stable example # use just the first word as sort key
foo baz
foo bar
quux ping
$ sort -k 1,1 --stable -u example # suppress lines with the same first word
foo baz
quux ping
```

but

```
$ sort -k 1,1 --stable example | uniq
foo baz
foo bar
quux ping
```

Comment: I understand the implications of using additional parameters, but i was just wondering about the basic functionality as in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is 'uniq -c' can count (and print) the number of matches. You lose this ability when you use 'sort -c' for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

They should be functionally equivalent, and `sort -u` should be more efficient.

I'm guessing the examples you're looking at simply didn't consider (or didn't have) "sort -u" as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Does `uniq` sort? 
I do not think so...
Because, at least on `Ubuntu 18.04` and `CentOS 6`, it does not. It will just remove consecutive duplicates.

You can simply conduct a mini experiment.

Let the file `sample.txt` be:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

`cat sample.txt | uniq` will output:

```
a
b
a
b
```

while `cat sample.txt | sort -u` will output:

```
a
b
```

`sort | uniq` may be functionally equivalent to `sort -u`.